# Persistent xampp phpmyadmin error

Tags: php, xampp

When I click my phpmyadmin page, it gives me this error: phpMyAdmin was unable to read your configuration file!
This might happen if PHP finds a parse error in it or PHP cannot find the file.
Please call the configuration file directly using the link below and read the PHP error message(s) that you receive. In most cases a quote or a semicolon is missing somewhere.
If you receive a blank page, everything is fine.

I downloaded xampp earlier today and uninstalled because it was giving me errors. So I just re-installed it now and I'm getting this error :(

I appreciate your suggestions, Thanks.

```
<?php
/*
* This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
* cookie
*/
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; 

/*
* Servers configuration
*/
$i = 0;

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';

/*
* End of servers configuration
*/

?>
```

Comment: This is a default install or have you changed anything?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything. This is my first click on the phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried going to the link it is asking you to access directly? What error is it giving you? That would help us determine what is wrong.

Comment: "Starting to parse config file..." and does nothing else

Comment: Could you post the information in your config file being mindful to comment out anything sensitive you wouldn't want to display publicly? It should be config.inc.php in the phpMyAdmin folder.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'd like to have you check the logs to see if there are any PHP errors.

Comment: I'm using windows 7, I clicked on the link for the error log and all it does it tell me: "Starting to parse config file..." and nothing comes after

Comment: Is $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] set correctly? I was also thinking it may be a permissions issue, especially on a windows install. Could you check xampp\apache\logs\error.log for any errors?

Comment: I just tried a wrong password....error.....refresh....worked!! Thanks a lot! You made my day!!